# How to add a QLabel(clickable link) to QWizard's button layout

Tags: qt, user-interface, qlabel, custom-widgets

I would like to add a clickable blue link (QLabel) right next to 'Next' button on one of my QWizardPages(subclassed) so the wizard's button layout would look like:

[Cancel]                                                          MyLabel  [Next]

I found out that you can add up to 3 custom buttons (QAbstractbutton) but no information about other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be a label. You can style a button to make it appear like a label would.